# iOS: Simple UIVIew not getting added to another UIView

Tags: ios, ios7

I have a storyboard driven iOS application.
**My objective is to add a small square view (defined as other XIB) to another UIView which is on main ViewController.**
**// Please note that, I have assigned the Class names in Identity Inspector correctly**

On the main ViewController, I added a UIView (myHolderView) manually and added a UIView member in the ViewController interface.

```
//.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *myHolderView;
@end
```

And, I have connected this IBOutlet by "BlueString" :)

Now, I have added another XIB with single view - Called it MySquare.xib and added a label on it.
And, added a UIView class with a .h and .m files. And, "BlueString" connections are made.

```
@interface MySquare : UIView
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@end
```

Now, in the implementation:

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myHolderView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MySquare *sq=[[MySqure alloc]init];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self.myHolderView addSubview:sq];
}
```

When I run it in the simulator, it just shows the main view, but on it the square view is not coming.
I know that main view had loaded because... I changed the colour of it so that I could see.
Please help.

Comment: Hi! Do you have any success solving this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't do in your *MySquare.m* file the view initialisation using your xib.

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    NSLog(@"This is called if you add programatically this view");
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self addSubview:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyIBView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

If you plan to add your xib using Interface Builder, you have to implement similarly the *initWithCoder* method:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        [self addSubview:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyIBView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

*Plese go through in this checklist, it might help others too:*

**Checklist adding a custom view with Interface Builder layout (xib):**

1) create a new xib (File->New->IOS/User Interface->View), name it (eg. MyIBView)

2) create a new class (File->New->IOS/Cocoa Touch->Objective-C class), make sure it is a Subclass of UIView!   Name it MyIBView.

Now you have MyIBView.xib, MyIBView.h and MyIBView.m  files added to your project

3) Edit your MyIBView.xib: select the File's owner and using the Identity inspector (3rd icon) select Class you created recently, MyIBView.

4) Select the top level View (if its a new xib, only this exists) and make sure using the Identity inspector that the Class is UIView (grey) and not overwritten

5) Now you can add IBOutlets and/or IBActions to your MyIBView.h file and you can do connections using Interface Builder in your MyIBView.xib

**Using this view programatically in another view:**

6a) Create the first method (initWithFrame) above in your MyIBView.m file if you would like to use this custom view programatically

7a) include your MyIBView.h file where you would like to add your custom view programatically

8a) now you can add your view:

```
     MyIBView *myIBView = [[MyIBView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
```

**Using this view in Interface Builder in another view:**

6b) Create the second method (initWithCoder) above in your MyIBView.m file if you would like to use this custom view in Interface Builder

7b) In your another view drop an UIView to your view canvas. Adjust the size and modify the Class using the Identity inspector to MyIBView.

Please note that you cannot see design time your custom view, only after trying to run the code.

Hope it helps, and you can find your miss-configuration!

Comment: Thanks Codedad! The first solution worked for me!  But the second one is actually my scenario!  That should be working. But when I added the second solution, the loop is becoming infinite at that statement. Can you please add something to this problem?

Comment: Please check your setup against this checklist. What causing the infinite loop that your xib gets initialized based on Interface Builder setup and parallely it is initialized and added as subview by the code so the Interface Builder setup again starts..  If this checklist does not help, you can upload your project to github so I can check it. I use this checklist in my projects so it should work ;-)